# Firebase Dynamic Link not opening app when access from Instagram

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

Firebase dynamic link is not opening the app when the link is clicked from the Instagram, it opens PlayStore while if I access the same link with WhatsApp, Chrome, or message app it opens the app and navigates to a specific location where I want.

Already added autoVerify=true in AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add host and scheme also

in intent-filter Please refere below code
or check
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos" !-->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
</intent-filter>




<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos" !-->
    <data android:scheme="example"
          android:host="gizmos" />

</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This answer does not work. Without the correct scheme, apps cannot reach the app via deep link. he already can use it via whatsapp etc